# Source Port vs Destination Port

Tags: tcp, port, firewall, outbound, inbound

I am new to TCP/IP and trying hard to learn basics. Well, I really wonder about inbound rules and outbound rules of Firewall and concept of source adress:port, destination adress:port.

For example I am investigating port 80. I know that http uses port 80. But when I try to listen the traffic I see that my browser doesn't use 80. As you see from the image only destination port 80 is used and "destination" should be the server that hosts web pages not my computer. And also there is no used port 80 on source port, "source" should be my computer.

[image]

My browser uses some other ports as source and goes to server port 80. From that, I understand that port 80 of my computer is not used for http, only server computers that host the web pages used port 80 but if I close port 80 or my computer from outbound rules the internet dooesn't work. But as I understood before from the image, port 80 is not used on my computer.

Really confused. Can anybody clarify it for me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are right : the communication goes from your computer (source port chosen "randomly") to a web server (destination port 80). And from a web server (source port 80) to your computer (destination port xxxxx) for the server's responses.

If you close port 80 in outbound rules, your computer will not be able to access any web server because this rule means that your firewall drops any packets which are send from your computer to a destination on port 80.

**EDIT**

Actually, the packets you send contains parameters such as :

```
Your_IP, Server_IP, Source_port (xxxxx), Destination port (80)
```

When your firewall sees that kind of packet, it applies the outbound rules **(the one concerning the communication FROM your computer TO a web server).**  If your outbound rule is to close port 80 (which means to drop any packets whose destination port is 80) it is normal to see the packets you try to send to a web server getting dropped.

closing port 80 in outbound rules doesn't mean you close your computer's port 80. It means your firewall drops packets whose destination port is 80.